# How to identify which os process is establishing a proxy connection

Tags: proxy, redhat, netstat

Platform: Red-Hat 7

I hope you can help me with this. I've been told that one proxy server we are using is going to be decommissioned in the following days. I've tried to use `netstat` in order to identify which application/os process is actually using it. But I can get the information I need

```
[root@hcbae2p01ora005 ~]# netstat -nap | grep :8080
tcp        0      0 180.210.107.196:19990   98.158.252.164:8080     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 180.210.107.196:19994   98.158.252.164:8080     TIME_WAIT   -
```

From the command above, I can see that some processes are trying to communicate with the old proxy ( 98.158.252.164 ). Now I need to know which application/process is trying to connect to that proxy ?

What option should I use in `netstat` to get that information ?

If I use `netstat -nlp` I am not able to get a relationship between the process and the destination IP of the proxy

```
[root@hcbae2p01ora005 ~]# netstat -nap | grep :8080
tcp        0      0 180.210.107.196:20352   98.158.252.164:8080     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 180.210.107.196:20354   98.158.252.164:8080     TIME_WAIT   -

[root@hcbae2p01ora005 ~]# netstat -nlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12769/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:26583         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2586/mdsd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7066            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12679/p_ctmag
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46301         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12789/p_ctmat
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2016          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4984/oraagent.bin
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:29218         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12486/java
```

Can anyone help me ?
Thanks

**Update**

The flag `-l` does not help me in this case

```
[root@hcbae2p01ora005 ~]# while true ; do  
> var=$(netstat -nap | grep :8080 | wc -l); 
> if [ $var -gt 0 ] ; then  netstat -nap | grep :8080;  netstat -l; fi;
> sleep 4; 
done
tcp        0      0 180.210.107.196:24046   98.158.252.164:8080     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 180.210.107.196:24034   98.158.252.164:8080     TIME_WAIT   -
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:26583         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7066            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:46301         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:bootserver    0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:29218         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:37258         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25324           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:sunrpc          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 hcbae2p01ora00:ncube-lm 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 hcbae2p01ora005:livelan 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 localhost:bootserver    [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:oem-agent          [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:19206              [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:sunrpc             [::]:*                  LISTEN
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:48561           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:52760           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:55610           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:bootpc          0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:sunrpc          0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 localhost:323           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:rlzdbase        0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10874           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:12325           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:13694           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:15890           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:16467           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17659           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22691           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:23727           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 localhost:25224         0.0.0.0:*
udp   262912      0 localhost:25229         0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:31064           0.0.0.0:*
udp6       0      0 localhost:32577         [::]:*
udp6       0      0 localhost:43769         [::]:*
udp6       0      0 localhost:51276         [::]:*
udp6       0      0 localhost:52160         [::]:*
udp6       0      0 localhost:53492         [::]:*
udp6       0      0 [::]:sunrpc             [::]:*
udp6       0      0 localhost:323           [::]:*
udp6       0      0 [::]:rlzdbase           [::]:*
udp6       0      0 [::]:oem-agent          [::]:*
udp6       0      0 localhost:14971         [::]:*
udp6       0      0 localhost:30392         [::]:*
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     37072    /etc/opt/omi/conf/sockets/omi_UujxgW0gO
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     39101    /var/lib/sss/pipes/pam
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     36952    /var/lib/sss/pipes/nss
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16056    /var/lib/sss/pipes/ssh
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     44128    /var/lib/sss/pipes/autofs
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10264    /run/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     21157    /var/uuidd/request
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10832    @CAgentStream_CloudAgentInfo_config_default_fluent.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     16437    /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10833    @CAgentStream_CloudAgentInfo_MaExtensionDiagnostics_default_fluent.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     49262    /var/tmp/.oracle/sprocr_local_conn_0_PROL
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10820    /var/run/mdsd/default_bond.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     36933    /var/run/lsm/ipc/simc
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10822    /var/run/mdsd/default_djson.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     36935    /var/run/lsm/ipc/sim
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10824    /var/run/mdsd/default_json.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     25164    /var/tmp/.oracle/ora_gipc_hcbae2p01ora005_INIT
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     26009    /var/tmp/.oracle/ora_gipc_scls_opct_hcbae2p01ora005
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10828    /var/run/mdsd/default_fluent.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     43924    /var/tmp/.oracle/sOHASD_IPC_SOCKET_11
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10830    /var/run/mdsd/default_influx.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     18290    /var/tmp/.oracle/sOHASD_UI_SOCKET
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     18292    /var/tmp/.oracle/sCRSD_UI_SOCKET
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     62638    /var/tmp/.oracle/s#5029.1
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     62641    /var/tmp/.oracle/s#5029.2
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     42088    /var/opt/omi/run/omiserver.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     19805    /var/lib/sss/pipes/private/sbus-monitor
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     43508    /var/lib/sss/pipes/private/sbus-dp_HCB.HCBE.CORP.1387
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     20616    /run/lvm/lvmpolld.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16526    /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     39102    /var/lib/sss/pipes/private/pam
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     39065    /run/gssproxy.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     69597    /var/tmp/.oracle/ora_gipc_css_ctrllcl_CSSD_BCCM
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     21154    /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     48846    /var/tmp/.oracle/ora_gipc_hcbae2p01ora005_EVMD
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     61616    /var/tmp/.oracle/sAevm
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     21158    /var/run/rpcbind.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     61620    /var/tmp/.oracle/sSYSTEM.evm.acceptor.auth
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     39098    /var/run/NetworkManager/private-dhcp
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     33979    /var/run/abrt/abrt.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     50333    /var/tmp/.oracle/ora_gipc_agent_ag_CSSDAG_z
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     50335    /var/tmp/.oracle/ora_gipc_monitor_ag_CSSDAG_z
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     39064    /var/lib/gssproxy/default.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     54945    /var/tmp/.oracle/sOracle_CSS_LclLstnr_localhost_1
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     54947    /var/tmp/.oracle/sOCSSD_LL_hcbae2p01ora005_localhost
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10834    @CAgentStream_CloudAgentInfo_HealthExtension_default_fluent.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     72063    /var/tmp/.oracle/ora_gipc_hcbae2p01ora005_CSSD
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     72076    /var/tmp/.oracle/sOCSSD_LL_hcbae2p01ora005_
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8413     /run/systemd/journal/stdout
```

**Update** with `lsof`

```
[root@hcbae2p01ora005 ~]# netstat -nap | grep :8080
tcp        0      0 180.210.107.196:11548   98.158.252.164:8080     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 180.210.107.196:11512   98.158.252.164:8080     TIME_WAIT   -
[root@hcbae2p01ora005 ~]# lsof -i | grep :8080
[root@hcbae2p01ora005 ~]#
```

Comment: The `-l` flag for `netstat` filters for listening ports only.

Comment: @JG7, if I use `-l` , then all the Foreign Address appear as either `0.0.0.0:*` for tcp or `[::]:*` for tcp6. Then I got a list of processes but without any relation to the destination IP

Comment: If you're on the server, which I assume you are, can you get a PID from `lsof -i`? If you know port 8080 is involved, then try `lsof -i :8080`. The PID should be the second column.

Comment: Please note, I meant "If you're on the client" in my last comment--assuming you are trying to figure out what process on your endpoint is interacting with the proxy.

Comment: @JGT, thank you for your support. I tried your approach, but nothing,. So I got two entries from `netstat` with status TIME_WAIT, but `lsof -i` does not find anything in that port

Comment: @JG7 , I updated the post with the result of `netstat` and `lsof`

Comment: did you combine all in all? `netstat -tulpn` might be a great source.